# Android ListView setOnItemLongClickListener works but setOnItemClickListener does not

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I wish to have a behaviour x when I click an item and a behaviour y when I push and hold the same item. I seem to be able to do one or the other, but not both.

So I have this Listview `lv`.
In `onCreate` I give it

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.v(TAG, "click position: " + position);
        }
    });
```

And when I click any item in my listview I get the log.

Say I remove the `setOnItemClickListener`. And now I add:

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
            Log.v(TAG, "long click position: " + position);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

When I do a long click (press and hold for 3s) I get the log. Yay.

But, if I try to use both together, the `setOnItemLongClickListener` eclipses the `setOnItemClickListener`. The `onItemClick` never gets called and only when I do a long click do I get the line logged.

The xml holding the items in the ListView has both:

```
android:longClickable="true"
android:clickable="true"
```

What fundamental concept about what I am trying to do did I get wrong?

Comment: You have set any on click listener in you adapter ? Or you have button or check box in your list item ? Can you post your list item xml and adapter code ?

Comment: The adapter that I am using has no listeners of any kind. Only 2 TextViews exist in the list item.

Comment: The code works fine here, maybe it's a problem in your textviews, maybe they request focus or something that prevents onClick events

Comment: @SaNtoRiaN indeed, problem came from the xml.

Comment: @hazyred good luck with that app :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ironically, from the xml containing my ListView items I removed the following:

```
android:longClickable="true"
android:clickable="true"
```

And now both listeners work as I intended them to!

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails you can use onTouch on the listview and use 2 threads to handle long touches and short touches. It becomes alot more of a pain, but this is how i built a dragNdrop listview and swipe to delete listview. I hope that gives you a start in a way to solve this.

Comment: If all else fails, something like that would be my plan B :). I want to first try and understand what I did wrong with this approach though.

Comment: I dont think you are doing anything wrong. I vaguely remember this being a problem for me, i tried everything i could till i just said forget it and did the thread way. Such a pain, but as far as i know the 2 clickers will conflict and one wont work. GL!